# What is the function to be used in Google sheets for calculating sum of an infinte row with confitional IF?

Tags: google-sheets

Assume I have two rows as below

```
  A                   B                      C
 Expendicture         By Whom               <Total Cost by Mr X>
  500                  Mr X                 <Total Cost By Mr Y>       
  300                  Mr Y                         
  463                  Mr Y                         
  764                  Mr X                         
  63                   Mr Y
```

Whats are the functions to find the cost of X and Y separately and paste it in Column C?
Assume columns A and B are infinite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Juse use SUMIF, same as in Excel but you can specify infinite range more easily:

```
=SUMIF($B$2:$B, "Mr X", $A$2:$A)
```

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BXMF_WTht6bXZtsMPqvP18yob9JCkSnidbJQ1J44Ad0/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: it works perfectly thank you. I used the same thing before posting the question without the $ symbol. Can you tell me what the $ is for?

Comment: see an article on absolute and relative references -  http://www.gcflearnfree.org/googlespreadsheets/14/full

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways would be a QUERY.. can you see if this works:

```
=query(A2:B, "select B, sum(A) where A is not null group by B label B 'Name', sum(A) 'Total Cost' ")
```

or, if you don't need the header rows

```
=query(A2:B, "select B, sum(A) where A is not null group by B  label sum(A) '' ")
```